# Delay in Passthrough Camera Feed in Unity Quest 3

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, oculusquest

I am developing a mixed reality application in Unity using the XR All-in-One plugin from the Unity Store with a target device being the Quest 3. I've successfully integrated the RigCamera, Hands, and Controllers tracking, as well as enabled passthrough using `BuildingBlocks`. However, I'm experiencing a noticeable delay in the passthrough feed from the real world — about half a second — while the virtual world interactions remain at full speed, causing a mismatch between the two.

Steps I've taken so far:

- Ensured all configurations in 'Project Settings -> Meta XR' are correct.
- Updated the project settings for Android build.
- Tested with Unity version 2022.3.20f1 LTS, as recommended by Meta.
- Enabled passthrough in the Oculus properties app

I've also [recorded a video](https://streamable.com/yk2j16) demonstrating the issue.
You can see how the virtual hands or/and controller react immediately when I move in the real world. However, the passthrough is really slow, causing this mismatch I have been talking about.

Does anyone know how to synchronize the passthrough feed with the virtual world and eliminate this delay? Any advice or insights would be greatly appreciated as I am really lost where the problem is coming from.